# I need help configuring my htaccess file properly

Tags: .htaccess

so I got this script from codester and I wasn't able to install it cause I keep getting errors like ".htaccess misconfigured" can anyone detect the error for me please, here is the .htaccess code

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewwriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule page/(.*)$ page.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule py$ _py.php [L]
RewriteRule payout$ pyt.php [L]
RewriteRule contact$ ct.php [L]
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Help

Comment: 2nd line is causing the error: RewwriteBase /

Answer (score 0):

There is a spelling mistake in your second line, use

> RewriteBase /

instead of Re**ww**riteBase /

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule page/(.*)$ page.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule py$ _py.php [L]
RewriteRule payout$ pyt.php [L]
RewriteRule contact$ ct.php [L]
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: That's great, in that case, could you please mark the answer as accepted :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers